# где найти? в корне сайта файл базы данных написанный JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Короче нашёл в интернете скрипт скачал и дальше решил подключиться к базе данных!
Вопрос где лежит файл к подключению к безе данных, я всегда ищу файл config но его тут нет помогите разобраться где он может быть (вот скриншот файлов сайта)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы скачали скрипт, на скриншоте у вас структура сайта в ней что то нужно найти. Где скрипт, зачем нужен скриншот структуры вашего сайта. Пока вопросов больше чем 1. Вам нужно улучшить вопрос

Answer (score 0):

> jQuery — набор функций JavaScript, фокусирующийся на взаимодействии JavaScript и HTML. Библиотека jQuery помогает легко получать доступ к любому элементу DOM, обращаться к атрибутам и содержимому элементов DOM, манипулировать ими. Также библиотека jQuery предоставляет удобный API для работы с AJAX.

Вы работаете с фронтендом (клиент), фронтенд не может на прямую взаимодействовать с базами данных, без использования бакенда (сервер). Здесь нет и не может быть никаких файлов конфигурации к базе данных.

- судя по вашему скриншоту, вы скачали какую-то ерунду.
  Возможно, вам нужен NodeJS